# conditional check with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my MVC view I need to display values in model object.

```
@model List<School.Model.Student_Model>
```

In a table I am displaying those student data.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RegisterDate)</td>
    </tr>            
}
```

RegisterDate is nullable `DateTime?`

In my tabel I like to display message **"date is not provided"**  if RegisterDate is null.

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RegisterDate.HasValue?item.RegisterDate.HasValue.ToString():"-")</td>
```

if I use above it gives me following error

**Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.**

I will  be able to do this if I use separate If- else condition.

```
@if(item.RegisterDate.HasValue)
{
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RegisterDate)</td>
}
else
{
    <td>date is not provided</td>
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an empty template for null fields :

```
//EmptyTemplate.cshtml
@(Model == null ? "NULL" : Model)
```

And call it in your DisplayFor method :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RegisterDate, "EmptyTemplate")
```

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayTemplates` and `EditorTemplates` must be named based on model type's name (a `MyClass` model will require a `MyClass.cshtml` as `DisplayTemplate`). It works the same for nullable types, although you can't add `?` or `<>` in a file name. Create a `DisplayTemplate` in the `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates` folder named `DateTime.cshtml` :

```
@model DateTime?

@(Model.HasValue ? string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Model.Value) : "date is not provided")
```

It can be used in your view like this :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RegisterDate)
```

You don't have to specify template's name, it will be found by convention.